# How can I do a boolean | undefined vs boolean | null PropType?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, react-proptypes

I have:

```
const propTypes = {
  ... // some other stuff
  disableEscapeKeyDown: PropTypes.bool,
};
export type ModalProps = PropTypes.InferProps<typeof propTypes>;

export default function ModalWindow({
  ...// other stuff
  disableEscapeKeyDown = false,
}: ModalProps) {
  const classes = useStyles({ width });
  return (
    <Modal
      open={open ?? false}
      onClose={onClose}
      disableEscapeKeyDown={disableEscapeKeyDown}
    >
```

But that gives me an error: `Type 'boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.`

It seems that a MUI Modal takes `boolean | undefined` whereas the PropType has it has `boolean | null`. How can I reconcile that?

Comment: null is pretty stupid in case of primitive component prop values like boolean. Anyway you can create [custom validator](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Check for `null`:

```
    <Modal
      open={open ?? false}
      onClose={onClose}
      disableEscapeKeyDown={disableEscapeKeyDown === null ? undefined : disableEscapeKeyDown}
    >
```

or you can also use `??`:

```
disableEscapeKeyDown ?? undefined
```

Option 2: Omit & intersect with correct type:

```
export default function ModalWindow({
  disableEscapeKeyDown = false,
}: Omit<ModalProps, "disableEscapeKeyDown"> & { disableEscapeKeyDown?: boolean }) {
```

Option 3: Change the definition of `ModalProps`:

```
type ModalProps = PropTypes.InferProps<Omit<typeof propTypes, "disableEscapeKeyDown">> & { disableEscapeKeyDown?: boolean };
```

Option 4: Ignore TypeScript:

```
    <Modal
      open={open ?? false}
      onClose={onClose}
      //@ts-ignore
      disableEscapeKeyDown={disableEscapeKeyDown}
    >
```

Unfortunately, I don't think you can "overwrite" or change how `PropTypes.InferProps` works - even trying to redefine `Requireable<T>` and `Validator<T>` did not work (at least my attempts to do it). So here's the next best thing: patching the results of the type yourself.

[Playground with all the options](https://tsplay.dev/NVb5ZN)